# How do I take COCO formatted json and compare them to ground truth images?

Tags: python, json, image-processing, scikit-image, pycocotools

I am looking for some help with COCO jsons.
I have a set of images that I have labelled with 10 sided polygons (blue blobs).
I have another set of images with the ground truth areas (yellow blobs).
I want to compare the area/number of pixels of the blue blobs with the yellow blobs.
I have labelled the dataset with bounding boxes and converted them to COCO formatted jsons.

[The ground truth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYEmI.png)

[The image that has been labelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYa5C.png)

[The json containing the polygon coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uxOh.png)

Do I need a COCO to CSV converter? Some sort of masking thing?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please embed the images instead of linking them

Comment: You should probably compare the images directly rather than converting to json for comparison !

Comment: @Maccesch unfortunately I can't as I am a new user

Comment: @endive1783 hmm ok, its just that I need to use the exact coordinates of the bounding boxes that I have drawn

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question then... Is your question about extracting the polygon coordinates from the COCO json ?

Comment: Yes I want to extract the polygon coordinates then create an array with those polygons filled in, then I will compare that array with another array for overlap and intersection. But I do not know how to extract the coordinates of the polygons for to create an array with those coordinates?